# Should I use the progressive aspect or not?

Tags: progressive-aspect

1. > He seldom has fatty food.
2. > He is seldom having fatty food.

Choose the correct alternative out of the above two sentences.  Please specify the reason as well. Grammatically, I believe both are correct.

Comment: Are you sure the second one is grammatically correct ?

Comment: If you think they are both correct, then what do you think are the differences between the two? When might we use the first, and when might we use the second?

Comment: Unable to answer your questions. But, I find both of these sentence have only tense difference.  First is present perfect which strongly emphasise on the present however action already done. The second sentence is present continuous which shows the continuity of the action. We do say, I am having dinner. So, is it that here its not showing any continuity but we are just referring to someone's habit so we need not use having fatty food?

Comment: @JMB : Replied to your question.

Comment: In American English, I would say: *He is seldom eating fatty foods* and it is grammatical. Of course, [context always helps](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77456/should-i-use-the-progressive-aspect-or-not#comment149474_77467).

Answer (score 3):

It is not idiomatic American English (and I don't think it's idiomatic British English either) to say "he is seldom hav*ing* fatty food".

We use the simple present to express habitual practice.

> He seldom has fatty foods.
>
> He rarely eats fatty foods.

But if it's not habitual practice, but an exception to habitual practice, and the exception is not a one-time exception but is happening on an ongoing basis, then there would be a greater chance that we would use the progressive:

> He's rarely eating fatty foods *these days*.
>
> He rarely eats fatty foods these days.

Addendum:

As the "these days" example suggests, we might choose the progressive to convey the idea that what we're doing now is different from what we used to do, or is different from what used to be the norm.

> I rarely eat meat.
>
> I'm rarely eating meat now.
>
> They rarely go in to the city to shop.
>
> People are rarely going into the city to shop now.

The first example with "now" would imply that you used to eat meat frequently, the second that people used to go into the city to shop regularly. That implication is what motivates the speaker's choice of progressive here. The adverb is needed, or the context must have established this now-then situation...or the speaker is thinking to herself about how things used to be different.

The aspect reveals the speaker's mind. Ideally, speaker and listener will be on the same wavelength.  Adverbs help them get on the same wavelength, so that listening is not 50% mind-reading.

In other words, the progressive partners with infrequency only when there's an implicit or explicit context of prior frequency. Without such context, the simple present will be chosen.

By contrast, we do say things like:

> These idiots are *always* texting when they drive.

Comment: +1 Should a time adverbial like "*these days*" be always present in a sentence of the latter type ("exception to habitual practice")? Then that's a good feature for a learner to remember too.

Comment: @CopperKettle No, because *He's rarely eating fatty foods* is fine. I think the use of the contraction changes how the verb tense and grammaticality is perceived. I wouldn't say *He is rarely eating fatty foods* is much more idiomatic than the OP's sentence. Too, I've no idea about this so-called "exception to habitual practice" concept; sounds concocted. *He's always eating fatty foods (these days)* with or without 'these days' is just as good a sentence. Note that it is also with the contraction.

Comment: He's always eating fatty foods.  *He's rarely eating fatty foods.  I don't think the latter is "fine" i.e. commonly used.

Comment: @TRomano ^ Says you. But I don't agree.  Still no downvote from me, despite this "exception to habitual practice" statement.

Comment: "ongoing exception to habitual practice" is meant to address the "always...rarely" difference in use of the progressive. IMO, we tend not to use the progressive for the ongoing *non*-practice (he rarely eats fatty foods vs. he is rarely eating fatty foods) unless some implicit or explicit exception to a general rule is involved. <unusual>He's rarely getting into trouble. <usual>He's rarely getting into trouble *anymore*.

Comment: Okay, I hear you. But I'm not sure what *He's always eating fatty foods* has to do with expressing an exception. It expresses a norm.

Comment: The grammaticality of the structure is demonstrated by (or *in*)  context. A: Have you seen John? What's up with him? He's lost a lot of weight. B: Yeah, I know. He's no longer a lounge lizard. He is exercising. He is (or: He's) rarely/seldom eating fatty foods. He is blah blah blah. @Copperkettle

Comment: But the OP does not have **always**. It has **seldom**.

Comment: And your example about John's losing weight is an example of what I'm talking about. He used to be fat. That was his rule. Now his actions are proving to be an exception (ongoing) to that established rule of his. Your formerly fat John example is analogous to my "these days" and "anymore" examples.  The OP lacks such an implicit context or explicit adverbial reference establishing such a change-from-prior-norm context.

Answer (score -1):

They both look grammatical to me.

But I see a difference in the meaning:

> He seldom has fatty food.

This means that *in general* the subject seldom has fatty food.

This would be therefore more appropriate to describe the subject's *general* attitude towards fatty food.

> He is seldom having fatty food.

This means that *in the current (not better specified) range of time* the subject is seldom having fatty food.

This would be therefore more appropriate to describe the subject's attitude towards fatty food *in the current (not better specified) range of time*.